# Core location not ask permission from the User and methods are not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I'm trying to use core location in iOS 8 simulator, for that I added in my view an object of type `'MapKit View'`, In tab **Atributtes inspector** is checked the option `show user location`, In my project I'm using **ARC**, below is the structure of my code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MeuPrimeiroViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>{

    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
}


@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
    @synthesize locationManager;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {

            NSLog(@"CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled == ON");

            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            locationManager.delegate = self;

            locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

            // Check for iOS 8 Vs earlier version like iOS7.Otherwise code will
            // crash on ios 7
            if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector
                 (requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
                [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            }

            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];




        }else{

            NSLog(@"CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled == OFF");
        }


    }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

   NSLog(@"It works this method is called");

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

  NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);

}
```

In my `info.plist` file I add this key `(NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription)` with this value `(String)`.

If I go to attributes inspector and enable the checkbox (shows user location) I receive this error message, and core location methods are not called:

```
 Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

If I disable the checkbox, this message disappear, and core location methods not called again. I try to change the navigation to `londom`, try to change location to `free run` but nothing I tried worked, the methods do not continue to be called and never showed an empowering message to use core location. I believe I've already tried everything, anyone have any suggestions or a solution to this problem?

Comment: I think you need one more entry in Info.plist file, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription. Also, for iOS 8 authorization status should be kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways

Comment: Well @Puran I add this keys and now my info.plist, have 3 keys (NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.,kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways,NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription ), I try to enable and disable show user location, and not works, any more else?

Comment: added the code i use below. Also kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways doesn't need to be in Info.plist it's just authorization type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i am doing for my app and working perfectly

```
- (void)startSignificantChangeUpdates {
    if (nil == self.locationManager) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    if (location) {
        self.currentLocation = location;
        NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude];
        NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude];

        self.latLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",latitude, longitude];
    }
    if (!self.geocoder)
        self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
         if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             if (placemark.postalCode) {
                 self.currentZipCode = placemark.postalCode;
             }
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"zipCodeFoundNotification" object:self.currentZipCode userInfo:nil];
         } else {
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"zipCodeFoundNotification" object:nil userInfo:nil];
         }
     }];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized && status != kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
            self.currentZipCode = @"kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied";
        } else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
            self.currentZipCode = @"kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted";
        }
    }
}
```